# how to reproduce this edittext attribute in Java on Android

Tags: android

how would I get the same effect of having a phone keyboard with only digits which I would get using these xml attributes

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

using Java and `setInput` or `setRawInput`?

Answer (score 1):

Try programmatically like below:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```